# No module named selenium even after installing it

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have installed selenium using "pip install selenium" on mac.
Also created a file functional_tests.py . It's content are

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

when I run this script using `python3 functional_tests.py` , I get: `no module named selenium`.

Comment: try `pip3 install selenium`. Your version of pip is likely for python 2.7

Comment: Thanks..It worked !

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems you are installing your packages globally. It is recommended to use a virtual environment so that you can keep the packages tied closely to each project.

This is how you do it on Mac with Python 3:

```
$ cd <project_dir>
$ python3 -m venv venv # creates the directory ./venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
# you have now the virtual environment running using python3 and pip3
(venv)$ pip install -U pip setuptools
(venv)$ pip install selenium
```

For your tests, consider using Django's `TestCase` (Selenium might require the `LiveServerTestCase`) and test procedure in order to run:

```
(venv)$ ./manage.py test  # this will run all of your tests
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/